# If Loop inside of While Loop causes infinite loop

Tags: php

I'm trying to loop through the first 5 items of an array that contain a specific value.

The code below causes an infinite loop.

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < 5):
    if ($counselor[$i]->state == $state || !$state): 
       // do stuff
       $i++; 
    endif;
endwhile;
```

Essentially I want to end the loop after the if statement has run 5 times.

Comment: @gogaz yep, I like to call it "longhand", I find it especially useful in files that also contain HTML

Comment: #jeremy, based on your comments, I can see that you have a misunderstanding with the concept of conditional statements i.e. if-else blocks.

Comment: @Arvind - I understand loops and else blocks. What I can't wrap my head around is running an if statement exactly 5 times.

Comment: #jeremy, consider debugging `var_dump($counselor[$i]->state,$state)` without using if-else block inside the loop for let say `while(count($counselor))`

Comment: If your if statement is false the first time ($i = 0) it will never match...since $i always will be 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While others have explained why your solution currently does not work, and some ways around it, the best alternative is to loop the entire array until you find 5 matches - by using a `foreach`-loop instead.

By using an `foreach`-loop, you will never run into issues if the array has less than 5 matching elements (if it has less than 5 matching elements, it will never break).

```
$i = 0;
// Loop the array
foreach ($counselor as $k=>$v) {
    // Check if there is a match
    if ($v->state == $state || !$state) {
        // Do whatever if a match here
        $i++;
    }
    // If we have found 5 matches, break out of the loop!
    if ($i == 5) {
        break;
    }
}
```

You can now check how big `$i` is, and if less than 5, you found less than 5 matches. If it's exactly 5, you found your matches, and ended the loop.

Answer (score 2):

If the if statement is not met, then you will only stay checking the `$counselor[0]->state`.

You need a separate counter for when the if statement is met.

```
$i = 0;
$containsCount = 0;
while ($containsCount < 5 || !isset($counselor[$i])):

    if ($counselor[$i]->state == $state || !$state):
        // do stuff
        ++$containsCount;   
    endif;
    ++$i;

endwhile;
```

I've also added a bounds check by checking if the $counselor[$i] is null. (could also check `$i < $arrayLength`)

Answer (score 1):

If your if statement is false the first time ($i = 0) it will never match...since $i always will be 0. The same goes for $i = 1, 2, 3 or 4. If any of those are false, the loop will be stuck. $i will never increase. You need another solution.

Answer (score 0):

You increment `$i` only when the if statement returns true. If you take your `$i++;` out of the if statement the loop will always run exactly 5 times.

```
$i = 0;
while($i < 5):

    if($counselor[$i]->state == $state || !$state): 
       // do stuff
    endif;
    $i++; 

endwhile;
```

Comment: This runs the while loop 5 times, regardless of how many times the if loop runs. I need to run the if loop exactly 5 times.

Comment: Then your original code was correct. But it is not a save way of doing it. You have a chance that your if statement is never true and therefore never gets to 5. This will indeed cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Just looking at your code again, is it an option to change the while loop to a for loop? Where you run through the whole `$counselor` array and then have a break after 5 successful if statements or otherwise it will stop once you reach the end of the `$counselor` array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to exit `$i++` of your `if` condition :

```
$i = 0;
while($i < 5):

    if($counselor[$i]->state == $state || !$state): 
       // do stuff
    endif;
    $i++; 

endwhile;
```

Comment: This runs the while loop 5 times, regardless of how many times the if loop runs. I need to run the if loop exactly 5 times.

Comment: You got an infinite loop because you never pass into your `if` condition. You have to limit the while to avoid infinite loop. Are you sure then you r `if` condition is not always `false`?

Answer (score 0):

if the if() condition is not met 5 times, it will be infinite as the while() condition will never be met.
Instead of while statement, use a loop that matches the length of the array and it will end then when it reaches the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try altering your if statement a bit like this :

```
$i = 0;
while($i < 5):

    if($counselor[$i++]->state == $state || !$state): 
       // do stuff
    endif;

endwhile;
```